# Glossed narratives in languages with proximate/obviative and/or direct/inverse marking?

Tags: resource-request, annotated-data

This is something of a long shot, but I am looking for narratives with English word-by-word glosses in languages that have proximate/obviative marking, direct/inverse marking (aka hierarchical alignment), or preferably both.

What I want to know is how frequently in such narratives, and at what points in the narrative, you get topic switching, where a new referent becomes the proximate topic, and also whether and how this is overtly marked. In other words, how continuous the status of something as 'proximate' tends to be, and where in a narrative discontinuity tends to occur. For this, I need word-by-word glosses of naturally occurring narratives, because a translation by itself won't show the proximate/obviative morphology.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would look at the Algonquian languages (Meskwaki, Ojibwe, Arapaho, Blackfoot, Migmaq etc.). They display both obviation and personhood hierarchies, and have fairly good collections of published glossed texts. To start out, check out the work of Ives Goddard (the high priest of Algonquian linguistics), Richard Rhodes, Amy Dahlstrom, and John Nichols; you should find something in there. This topic has been pretty well looked-at in the literature, so if all you're interested in is descriptions of what you mention, you can probably already find it in these peoples' published work, and you probably won't have to do your own research (which is not to discourage you if you think you can find something they've missed.) Also, Alfred Kiyana, who was a native speaker of Meskwaki, wrote down quite a few stories that have since been glossed. I'm sorry that I can't give you any texts off the top of my head, but the names I listed should lead you pretty quickly to what you want. Also, for what it's worth, here's a dissertation on obviation in Meskwaki if you're interested in taking a look at the ground that's already been covered: http://repositories.lib.utexas.edu/bitstream/handle/2152/990/thomasonlg036.pdf

Good luck!